# Space letter second line lettrine package

Tags: lettrine

I am using the `lettrine` package. I am struggling with the options influencing the distance of the second line. How do I decrease the space where the red arrow points at and move the text closer to the T?
[image: Lettrine]

Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\section{New Section}
\lettrine{T}{he} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is the `nindent` option. According to the manual:

> nindent= "dimen" shifts all indented lines, starting from the second
>   one, horizontally by "dimen" (this shift is relative to the first
>   line, default=0.5em);

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lettrine}

\begin{document}

\section{New Section}
\lettrine[nindent=-4pt]{T}{he} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: Lettrine]

Comment: Thank you! Obviously I have not been looking thoroughly enough.